# Как убрать слэш в конце урла поста, в урле категории оставить?

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать урлы типа?:

```
mysite.com/mycategory/
mysite.com/mycategory/post
```

Через админку в постоянных ссылках можно делать либо все со слэшем на конце либо все без слэша.

Comment: Вопрос как почему у тебя их нет.. Из коробки всё со слешем.

Comment: Спасибо. Отредактировал вопрос. Взгляните пожалуйста еще раз.

Answer (score 1):

Настройки -> Постоянные ссылки -> Произвольно -> /%postname%/
Скорее всего ты убрал последний символ.

Comment: Спасибо. Отредактировал вопрос. Взгляните пожалуйста еще раз.

Answer (score 1):

Решил след. образом:

```
function no_page_slash( $string, $type ){
    if($type == 'single')
        $string = untrailingslashit($string);
   return $string;
}
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'no_page_slash', 70, 2);
```

При этом постоянные ссылки в админке должны быть настроены вот так: /%category%/%postname%/ .